# How to disable env HDR reflection only for one object?

Tags: rendering, world, hdri, reflection

I have scene with 2 objects, 1 light and background HDR.
For object 1 i need light reflection and background reflection.
For object 2 i need only light reflection without background.

Is any simple settings to quickly disable background reflections on specific objects for Cycles and Eevee?

I found something that looks like a solution here – [Remove Unwanted Reflections (Blender Cycles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfSiA5Wc8Ac&t=493s)
, but it's too complicated, is there a simpler solution?